# Cannot Scrape Innertext of <div> Nodes Level

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have these `<div></div>` structure.

```
<div class="RecentTrades">
    <div class="TradesRow TradesHeader">
        <div class="TradesDate">Date</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">Time</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">Trade Prc</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">Volume</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Buy/Sell</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">Bid</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">Ask</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">Value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="TradesRow TradesBG_G" style="color:#ff0000;">
        <div class="TradesDate">08-Jan-14</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">17:05:00</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">83.80</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">1,970,861</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Sell*&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">83.85</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">83.88</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">1.652<strong>M</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="TradesRow TradesBG_W" style="color:#ff0000;">
        <div class="TradesDate">07-Jan-14</div>
        <div class="TradesTime">16:30:11</div>
        <div class="TradesPrice">80.739</div>
        <div class="TradesVolume">40,000</div>
        <div class="TradesBuySell">Sell*&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="TradesBid">83.85</div>
        <div class="TradesAsk">83.88</div>
        <div class="TradesValue">32.30<strong>k</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my code to parse/scrape using HTMLAgilityPack.

```
private void btn_fetchTrades_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
                    {
                        var fileName = @"..\..\bin\Debug\ModifiedPages\recent2.htm";
                        // Load HTML
                        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                        doc.Load(fileName);

                        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='RecentTrades']"); 

                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"..\..\bin\Debug\ModifiedPages\" + "Trades.txt", FileMode.Append))
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                        {
                            // Iterate all rows in the relevant table
                            HtmlNodeCollection rows = node.SelectNodes(".//div");
                            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
                            {
                                // Iterate all columns in this row
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesDate']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols2 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesTime']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols3 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesPrice']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols4 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesVolume']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols5 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesBuy']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols6 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesSell']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols7 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesBid']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols8 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesAsk']");
                                HtmlNodeCollection cols9 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//div[@class='TradesValue']");
                                for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
                                    // Get the value of the column and print it
                                    sw.WriteLine(cols[j].InnerText + "," + cols2[j].InnerText + "," + cols3[j].InnerText + "," +
                                                 cols4[j].InnerText.Replace(",", "") + "," + cols5[j].InnerText + "," + cols6[j].InnerText + "," + cols7[j].InnerText + 

"," + cols8[j].InnerText + "," + cols9[j].InnerText + "," + "922");
                            }
                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.Close();
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
        }
```

But I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I must be doing something wrong with the nodes, but I cannot figure it out after so many hours. Would be great if anyone of you can look into it. Thank you very much!

Comment: set a breakpoint the line before the error... check the next lines with your watch debug window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know that in your HTML, you have a node with class "BuySell", but you're looking for Buy and Sell in the code, separately?  That would do it.  Please use your debugger.

Comment: OMG! :(( Thank you for that!! I am so careless! :(

Comment: I am a novice, and not good at using debugger, but I will definitely look into it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Codenoire, do you have idea why the code parse only the first inner `<div></div>`? I only get the headers.

Comment: Try changing "++i" to "i++"

Comment: It's still the same after changing to "i++".

Comment: I did debug it, and when the code runs through the `for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)` second round, the `cols, cols2...` values all becomes null. :/ I don't know why it happens when the second inner `<div></div>` is there.